# Need a simpler way of displaying this data without merging cells

Tags: excel

**Unmerged cells:**
[image: Unmerged Cells]

See attached screenshot. I want to show multiple limits/attachments/premiums for a single Insured/broker/industry.

I've tried merging rows (see below) for Insured/broker/industry but then I am unable to filter and get all the data for each limit. (it only takes the first row)

**Merged Cells:**
[image: Merged Cells]

**Filtered Cells:**
[image]

Having it laid out with all the rows unmerged means I can filter the data, however it makes the page a little hard to read, especially as it gets larger and larger.

Does anyone have any ideas for displaying the data in a different way?

Comment: Have you looked at a Pivot Table?

Comment: How about conditional formatting? if the cell above has the same value then numberformat `;;;`and no border at top... will kinda look like what you want...

Comment: @DirkReichel Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @radiocontrolled I haven't been able to get it to work .. I think it's because there are multiple limits with the same amount that tie to different attachments

Comment: VTC and move to [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) since this is less about "programming" Excel and more about working within the application to format.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Ok - I'll do that, but what's VTC?

Comment: VTC = Vote-to-close.